# finetuning tensorflow seq2seq model

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, machine-translation, word-embedding

I've trained a seq2seq model for machine translation (`DE-EN`). And I have saved the trained model checkpoint. Now, I'd like to **fine-tune this model checkpoint to some specific domain data samples** which have not been seen in previous training phase. Is there a way to achieve this in tensorflow? Like modifying the embedding matrix somehow.

I couldn't find any relevant papers or works addressing this issue.

Also, I'm aware of the fact that the vocabulary files needs to be updated according to new sentence pairs. But, then do we have to again start training from scratch? Isn't there an easy way to **dynamically update the vocabulary files and embedding matrix** according to the new samples and continue training from the latest checkpoint?

Comment: This is a generic case. This is not possible in a `seq2seq` setting where I need to update the vocabulary according to the new samples. what you're suggesting can only work for continuing training. It doesn't handle new sentence pairs

Comment: Ah okay, but by increasing the vocabulary you will have to change the embedding matrix dimension as well, thus introducing new parameters.

Comment: Yes, that's right! But, isn't there a smarter way to `append only embeddings` for new words added to vocabulary to the already existing `embedding matrix`? I guess this could facilitate training from latest checkpoint but I'm unsure though.